# How can I set up a cell style that is ascending dates?

Tags: front-end, date-and-time, stylesheet, cells

Outline style notebooks have cell counters that are simply ascending numbers, but what if I want to apply a function to them and have descending dates like this:

[image]

So that they auto format and the notebook is still usable (i.e. no crazy continuous dynamics), is this even possible?

Comment: You would probably have to read the notebook, find the `Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell["Sunday, February 8 2015", "Section"],...` grouped cells, convert the strings to absolute time, reorder and write back to the notebook. Unlikely to work if there are spelling errors such as in your screen grab since that will preclude any conversions from date strings to absolute time for sorting.

Comment: So these "higher level" dynamic counter objects I'm looking for, are not one offs. that is, this level of customization is not really supported in notebooks? Oh and for some reason the @username syntax isn't working in this comment on Chrome right now...

Comment: Dates are entered by you, right? and you want mma to sort sections, when exactly?