# How to sort cells?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

Is there a way to programmatically reorder the section cells in a notebook alphabetically?

For example:
[image]

Comment: I think a similar question has been asked before, possibly relating to cells that are labeled by date, but I cannot find it now.  *Edit:* never mind, I seem to have been thinking of your own question: [(73544)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73544/121)

Comment: Yes very similar!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [2181](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2181/5478)? :)

Comment: My answer should work for you but it would be nice to have more details described. What if those sections are gouped by Titles for example.  Do you want to be able to do this only on selected part too. etc etc. I think a lot of such features may be implemented, I just don't like to think what others may need for edge cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will try to add a more general function later, meanwhile you can use this procedure:

```
Module[{cells, data},

 cells = Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"];

 data = (
     SelectionMove[#, All, CellGroup, AutoScroll -> False];
     NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]]
     ) & /@ SortBy[cells, First@NotebookRead[#] &];

 Do[
  SelectionMove[cells[[i]], All, CellGroup, AutoScroll -> False];
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], data[[i]], AutoScroll -> False]
  ,
  {i, Length@cells}
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Oh no, I didn't realize this solution would destroy cell options like `Cell["Python", "Section", WholeCellGroupOpener->True]`

Comment: @M.R. well that's unexpected. Any other options behave strange? I've posted the question already: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86077/5478

Comment: @M.R. Using `"WholeCellGroupOpener"` works but I don't know why :)

Comment: @M.R. I've post a solution to the problem of `CellContext`: [102269](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102269/5478) so you can use this replacement rules.