# NotebookWrite a Cell with WholeCellGroupOpener option

Tags: functions, front-end, notebooks, options

Why

```
NotebookWrite[
  EvaluationNotebook[], 
  Cell["ZZ", "Section", WholeCellGroupOpener -> True]
]
```

produces:

> ```
> Cell["ZZ", "Section", $CellContext`WholeCellGroupOpener -> True]
> ```

While using e.g `Background -> RGBColor[1, .85, .85]` works fine?

Pointed by [M.R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/403/m-r) in [How to sort cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85828/5478)

Comment: Check `Options[Cell]` and try your example with all options that live in the context ``Gobal`` not ``System``. As far as I can see, all options that are not in ``System`` will get `$CellContext`.

Comment: @halirutan yep, that's what I've suspected. Unfortunately those options are not  documented so I already know what WRI support will say to me...

Comment: You could fake it: NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 Cell["ZZ", "Section", System`WholeCellGroupOpener -> True]]