# String option names for Cells

Tags: notebooks, syntax, options, cells

They seem to be correctly interpreted.

I'm asking because of some minor reasons and a major one: [NotebookWrite a Cell with WholeCellGroupOpener option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86077/5478)

I don't know any official confirmation so **let me just ask** if anyone knows where using string names for built in options names may fail.

Let's assume the context is only about `Cell` options.

---

As we can see, works well:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[TextData["Test"], "Input", "Background" -> LightBlue, 
  "CellFrame" -> True, "FontColor" -> Red]]
```

Cell expression (Ctrl+Shift+E) shows that `"Background"` was converted to `Background` but even if I manually edit the cell back to "Background" it understands it.

Comment: Thou shalt support other MMA User and thou shalt fight against Spam. +1

Comment: Maybe if the symbol does not exist in the System` context?

Comment: @RolfMertig It works well for both, System and Global, that's why I'd like to use it.

Comment: I like doing this too.  Makes for easier reading.  Please post if you find any options that are not supported this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've talked with [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz) and he **confirmed** this should work and be a stable remedy for the context problem linked above.