# Programming scripts to create and modify stylesheets: problems with contexts

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, stylesheet

I am trying to emulate the <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> feature in the `Outline.nb` stylesheet that comes with *Mathematica*.

I added the following code to a private stylesheet at the notebook level.

```
Cell[StyleData["NUM"],
 CellDingbat->Cell[
   TextData[{
     CounterBox["NUM"], "."}]],
 CellMargins->{{80, 10}, {7, 7}},
 ReturnCreatesNewCell->True,
 StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab" -> "SubNUM"},
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 50},
 DefaultNewCellStyle->"SubNUM",
 DefaultReturnCreatedCellStyle->"NUM",
 ParagraphIndent->0,
 CounterIncrements->"NUM",
 CounterAssignments->{{"SubNUM", 0}},
 MenuSortingValue->1200,
 MenuCommandKey->"1",
 FontFamily->"Times",
 FontColor->GrayLevel[0]]

Cell[StyleData["SubNUM"],
 CellDingbat->Cell[
   TextData[{
     CounterBox["SubNUM"], "."}]],
 CellMargins->{{120, 10}, {7, 7}},
 ReturnCreatesNewCell->True,
 StyleKeyMapping->{
  "Tab" -> "Outline3", "Backspace" -> "NUM", KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Shift}] -> "NUM"},
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 60},
 ParagraphIndent->0,
 CounterIncrements->"SubNUM",
 CounterAssignments->{{"Outline3", 0}},
 MenuSortingValue->1250,
 MenuCommandKey->"2",
 FontFamily->"Times",
 FontColor->GrayLevel[0],
 CounterBoxOptions->{CounterFunction:>(Part[
   CharacterRange["a", "z"], #]& )}]
```

So <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> work perfectly in the notebook containing the stylesheet. I tried them and they both work.

However, when if I create a new notebook and then apply the stylesheet to that notebook I loose the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> feature.  But for some reason the tab feature does transfer over.  It seems to break only the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> feature.  As you can see in the animated gif below, the tab key works, but <kbd>shift+tab</kbd> does not work.

[image]

---

I use the function below to apply the styles in my master stylesheet notebook to any notebook I am working in.

```
ApplyStylesheet:=Module[{nb,stylesheet},

nb=NotebookOpen[$HomeDirectory<>"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Ventura College/Mathematica/Master Settings/MStylesheet.nb"];
stylesheet=Options[nb,StyleDefinitions];
NotebookClose[nb];
nb=InputNotebook[];
SetOptions[nb,stylesheet];
];
```

---

Edit 2:  @Kuba - I was able to verify that your code below works like a charm.  However, I was still having issues using it in conjuction with my `ApplyStylesheet` function above.  As it turns out

`stylesheet=Options[nb,StyleDefinitions]`

was not saving the contexts.  As a solution for applying a master stylesheet to multiple notebooks, I name the master stylesheet configuration (like yours configuration below) and then call it within any notebook. Contexts are kept intact this way. Thank you!

Comment: I have multiple notebooks that I push a single stylesheet to.  I do this creating a master notebook and editing its stylesheet.  I than copy the styles of this master notebook and apply it to many notebooks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One has to be extremely careful with `Cell` options that are not released in `` System` `` context. It seems that your problem is caused by additional `` $CellContext` `` given to `KeyEvent` `Modifiers` and `Shift`.

I've faced it with earlier: [NotebookWrite a Cell with WholeCellGroupOpener option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86077/5478)

With

```
FrontEnd`KeyEvent["Tab", FrontEnd`Modifiers -> {FrontEnd`Shift}] -> "NUM"
```

*Stylesheet* works for me.

but it is not the only thing that won't work, you have to fix:

```
FrontEnd`DefaultNewCellStyle (*and*)
FrontEnd`DefaultReturnCreatedCellStyle (*and*)
FrontEnd`ReturnCreatesNewCell
```

too. Cumbersome...

- when I'm writing scripts to manipulate stylesheets I'm **using string names** for option names `"ReturnCreatesNewCell"` etc. Not documented but working. [String option names for Cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88856/5478)
- (***New edit:***) What if it is not you who specifies those options and you have to e.g. `NotebookWrite` cell contents that can have those not released symbols somewhere?

  - You can do a replacement just before doing this. Let's create a test cell: `Cell["asd", "Subsection", WholeCellGroupOpener->True]`, now put before that cell

    ```
    CellPrint[
      NotebookRead[
         NextCell[]
      ] /. s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "Global`" :> Symbol["FrontEnd`" <> SymbolName[s]]
     ]
    ```

    It will generate correct copy, while without replacement you'd end up with `` $CellContext` ``.
  - Or you can force those unknown symbols to be put in `` FrontEnd` `` context when read:

    ```
    CellPrint @ Block[
      {$Context = "FrontEnd`", $ContextPath = {"System`"}}, 
      NotebookRead[NextCell[]]
    ]
    ```

---

```
SetOptions[
  EvaluationNotebook[],
  StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["NUM"], 
     CellDingbat          -> Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["NUM"], "."}]], 
     ReturnCreatesNewCell -> True, 
     StyleKeyMapping      -> {"Tab" -> "SubNUM"}, 
     CellGroupingRules    -> {"SectionGrouping", 50}, 
     DefaultNewCellStyle  -> "SubNUM", 
     DefaultReturnCreatedCellStyle -> "NUM", 
     ParagraphIndent      -> 0, 
     CounterIncrements    -> "NUM", 
     CounterAssignments   -> {{"SubNUM", 0}}, 
     MenuSortingValue     -> 1200, 
     MenuCommandKey       -> "1"]
    ,
    Cell[StyleData["SubNUM"], 
     CellDingbat          -> Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["SubNUM"], "."}]], 
     CellMargins          -> {{120, 10}, {7, 7}}, 
     ReturnCreatesNewCell -> True,
     StyleKeyMapping      -> {"Tab" -> "Outline3", "Backspace" -> "NUM", 
          KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Shift}] -> "NUM"}, 
     CellGroupingRules    -> {"SectionGrouping", 60}, 
     ParagraphIndent      -> 0, 
     CounterIncrements    -> "SubNUM", 
     CounterAssignments   -> {{"Outline3", 0}}, 
     MenuSortingValue     -> 1250, 
     MenuCommandKey       -> "2", 
     FontFamily           -> "Times", 
     FontColor            -> GrayLevel[0], 
     CounterBoxOptions    -> {CounterFunction :> (Part[
           CharacterRange["a", "z"], #] &)}]
    }
   ]/. s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "Global`" :> Symbol["FrontEnd`" <> SymbolName[s]]
 ]
```

Comment: This works!  And it makes sense.  However, I do get an error in a dialog window saying "shift:show: Symbol Shift appears in multiple contexts {System', Global'}; definitions in context System' may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.  I've heard of this shadow error.  I'll see if I can find a way to get rid of it... as the code does work.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain not to `NUM` but to options names, take a look at edits.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain Hi, you may be interested in the New edit. p.s. please those comments that are no longer valid.