# Setting WholeCellGroupOpener

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, cells

When I write `WholeCellGroupOpener`, *Mathematica* autocompletes it, but it doesn't recognize it (it stays blue instead of turning black).

Example:

```
SetOptions[#, {CellOpen -> False, WholeCellGroupOpener -> False}] & /@
  Cells[ButtonNotebook[], CellStyle -> "Section", CellTags -> "A"]
```

And when I evaluate it, the correct cells are closed, but I can open them again by clicking on where they were.

If it is not possible to change `WholeCellGroupOpener` to false in this way, is there another way of disabling the cell so that it does not open when the user clicks on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that options not documented/released in `` System` `` context, are  renamed to e.g. `` $CellContext`WholeCellGroupOpener ``.

There is a more general topic about that: [**Programming scripts to create and modify stylesheets: problems with contexts**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102189/5478)

So what your code does is creation of such option (you can check cell expression with Ctrl+Shift+E) which doesn't mean anything.

I'd go with a string name:

```
SetOptions[#, {CellOpen -> False, "WholeCellGroupOpener" -> False}] & /@
  Cells[ButtonNotebook[], CellStyle -> "Section", CellTags -> "A"]
```

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if the code you posted is literal but in any case you need to be using `Alternative` instead of `Or`, i.e. `|` instead of `||`:

```
SetOptions[#, {CellOpen -> False, WholeCellGroupOpener -> False}] & /@
  Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], CellStyle -> ("Section" | "Subsection"),
   CellTags -> ("A" | "B")]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it does not solve my problem. If you click on the closed cell, it opens because WholeCellGroupOpener is still true.

Comment: you are correct. I had focussed my answer on the syntax errors you had prior to reading this answer and doing your edit