# How can I use CurrentValue in packages as it generates symbols in current context?

Tags: front-end, contexts

I just found that `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd,"ScreenInformation"]` will generate (some of) the symbols it uses as keys in the current context of the first evaluation (it might do so for other properties but "ScreenInformation" is the one I know of). To replicate evaluate the following in a fresh Kernel:

```
Block[{$Context = "testcontext`"},
     CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ScreenInformation"]
]
```

> ```
> {{testcontext`ScreenArea -> {{66, 1920}, {0, 1200}}, 
>   testcontext`FullScreenArea -> {{0, 1920}, {0, 1200}}, 
>   testcontext`BitDepth -> 32, 
>   testcontext`Resolution -> 
>    96}, {testcontext`ScreenArea -> {{-1280, 0}, {0, 1024}}, 
>   testcontext`FullScreenArea -> {{-1280, 0}, {0, 1024}}, 
>   testcontext`BitDepth -> 32, testcontext`Resolution -> 96}}
> ```

From now on, `CurrentValue` seems to always return (some) symbols in that context:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ScreenInformation"]
```

> ```
> {{testcontext`ScreenArea -> {{66, 1920}, {0, 1200}}, 
>   FullScreenArea -> {{0, 1920}, {0, 1200}}, 
>   testcontext`BitDepth -> 32, 
>   Resolution -> 
>    96}, {testcontext`ScreenArea -> {{-1280, 0}, {0, 1024}}, 
>   FullScreenArea -> {{-1280, 0}, {0, 1024}}, 
>   testcontext`BitDepth -> 32, Resolution -> 96}}
> ```

Which symbols are created in which context is somewhat random when I try it with 11.3 and seems to be different in a fresh frontend session than in a fresh kernel started from an existing frontend session.

Why is this a problem? If you will do something like:

```
ScreenArea /. First[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ScreenInformation"]]
```

in another context than the original this might not work as the context of `ScreenArea` might not match.

1. Would anyone agree that this is a bug?
2. What are suggested workarounds?

Comment: That's probably related by the root of the problem: [102189](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102189/5478)

Comment: @Kuba: Yes, seems related. One additional problem here is that using strings instead of symbols does not work (at least I could not find any way to make it work). And of course your comment there about undocumentd feature does apply here as well...

Answer (score 7):

my own current favorite workaround would be this:

```
"ScreenArea" /. Replace[
  CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ScreenInformation"],
  Verbatim[Rule][s_Symbol, v_] :> (SymbolName[s] -> v), {2}
]
```

it has the advantage that it should work independently on what context the symbols were generated in and it should work when the exact behavior will be changed (fixed?) in a future version. It will not only work when the symbols are generated in a specific well defined context but also when they will be changed to strings (as long as the names won't change). Of course I am still interested in other suggestions and any pointers to shortcomings of this solution...