# Keyboard Shortcuts in paclets?

Tags: keyboard, paclets

I’m trying to add simple keyboard shortcuts (together with menu item) to my paclet through FrontEndExecute which works fine in notebook, but as soon as I put it into my paclet and import it the menu item is stripped from the keyboard shortcut. Is this due to security requirements on paclets or is there perhaps a way around it?
I know about KeyEventTranslations.tr but I’d rather not use it.

Here's the minimal example about which I'm talking about:

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput",

{Delimiter, MenuItem["Test", FrontEndExecute@Print[2], 

MenuKey["d", Modifiers -> {"Command"}], System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]];
```

Comment: Try to replace `MenuKey` and `Modifiers` with ``System`MenuKey`` and ``System`Modifiers``, respectively. (Note how those two symbols are blue when you copy your code into a notebook, suggesting the kernel doesn't know about those symbols, meaning they will be created in the paclet context instead of the correct one when you execute your code from within a paclet)

Comment: It works! Thank you, that has been very quick and straight to the point!

Comment: closely related: [102189](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102189/programming-scripts-to-create-and-modify-stylesheets-problems-with-contexts)